# ClassNotFoundException on Guava

Tags: java, eclipse, guava

I'm getting a error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.net.InternetDomainName
```

when trying to run the following code:

```
private String getTopPrivateDomain(String url) {
   return InternetDomainName.from(url).topPrivateDomain().toString();
}
```

I have downloaded `guava-18.0.jar` and I have triple-checked that it exists in my build-path. I have also imported `com.google.common.net.*`. I get no errors or warnings in Eclipse and the program compiles fine, but it throws the above exception when the method is run.

I don't understand why it cannot find that class when it's clearly imported and in the build-path?

Comment: Hm...strange. If it wasn't existing at Runtime, then you'd receive a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jar isn't in the classpath location when it's being ran, but it is configured in Eclipse. If you're using Tomcat or something like that it'll need to be in a /lib directory

Comment: yeah I didn't know I had to do differently for Tomcat. I put it in the /lib directory and it worked fine. Cheers!

Comment: @Chris It is not a good idea to put the JAR into Tomcat's `lib` folder. Put it into your webapps's `WEB-INF/lib` folder instead.